# Are there Rotate Webview examples around?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, webview

I thought I had already asked this question but I cant see it so I will ask again.

I need to write an app which simply contains a webview that rotates.  How do I rotate the text when the user puts their phone from portrait to landscape or vice versa?

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 1):

This is handled automatically.  In your view controller, override the method:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return YES;
}
```

And make sure your webview's autoresizing mask is set like this:

```
webView.autoResizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: Hello

Thanks for your help are there examples for how to use the autoresizing dialog? 

It confuses me!

Not sure how to " make sure your webview's autoresizing mask is set to FlexibleWidth | FlexibleHeight"

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Are you controlling the UIWebView with a UIViewController? If so, override

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```